# Nginx 404 redirect to 404 dynamic custom template

Tags: django, nginx

I'm currently a problem for which I run out of solutions:

Quickly resume:
The project is write with Django, I have my custom 404 configured correctly and I have some specific urls that are stuck to the nginx 404 rendering instead of my django template.

Example: `mydomaine.org/en/%20`

My django 404 is a template, which means that it's dynamically link to a page within the CMS. I don't have a custom 404.html (or, let's say its writes with {% myheader %} etc )

So, here is my first try:
`rewrite ^/en/\s.*$ mydomain.org/en/404 permanent;`
but this return a `302` code and doesn't take the language in consideration.

So I tried something else:
`error_page 404 /404.html;` (but of course I don't have a proper template whatever)

```
location ~ /(?:en|fr|de|es|tr|ja)/\s.* {
    return 404 mydomain.org/$1/404;
}
```

doesn't work.

```
location ~ /(?:en|fr|de|es|tr|ja)/\s.* {
    error_page 404 mydomain.org/$1/404;
}
```

doesn't work.

```
location ~ /(?:en|fr|de|es|tr|ja)/\s.* {
    return 404;
}
```

Not the behaviour I want :(

Apparently I can only do a rewrite or show nginx 404? Nah I can't believe it, google uses its own template for [google.com/%20](http://google.com/%20) .

Does anyone have an idea? I'm completely lost.

Comment: As long as those specific URLs are still hitting the backend (going through a proxy_pass or something similar), Django should use your 404 template. Having Nginx return 404 or redirecting to `mydomain.org/$1/404;` won't do anything, because `mydomain.org/$1/404` would likely still go through the `proxy_pass` which amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, that's the point, I don't understand why for those urls django isn't rendering the 404 template.

Comment: Weird... What are the specific URLs? Do you have any caching mechanisms that might be serving old content?

Comment: the specific url are:
`mydomain.org/en/%20`
or `mydomain.org/%20`
I try to solve that, thus the weird url catcher '/en/\s.*$`.
But yes, indeed the website I'm currently working on is the 3rd website on the same domain name. I'm quite sure that older ones are interfering with it. I don't have any access about them at the moment.